# IBM MobileFirst Adapters security roles

Tags: security, ibm-mobilefirst, jax-rs, adapter

Is it possible to use [JAX-RS2 security roles](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/en/part1/chapter15/programmatic_security.html) in MF adapters?

E.g.:

> securityContext.isUserInRole("MyTestRole")

This method returns always false in my adapter. I added in "mfp" app (mfp-server.war) in server.xml (LibertyProfile):

```
<security-role name="MyTestRole">
  <group name="MyLDAPGroup" />
</security-role>
```

and I am logged in to user that is assigned to "MyLDAPGroup".

Or maybe in MF adapters we should use some other mechanism to specify roles?

Comment: What version of MF are you running ?

Comment: 8.0.0-2017012016

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the following links:

1. Implementing a JAX-RS resource & security configuration of a JAX-RS resource in MFP v8.0:
   https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHSCD_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_impl_java_adapter_JAXRS.html
2. Security framework in MFP v8.0:
   https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security

Comment: What I am looking for is possibility to login to MF app to e.g. "MyScope", and in "MyScope" can be many different users, but some of them have some special role in LDAP. And I want to force LibertyProfile server to check if logged user is allowed to use this adapter method or not by checking this on server level. Normally in JAX-RS we can use securityContext.isUserInRole("MyTestRole") but I can not achieve that on MF.

Comment: Ref: " I want to force LibertyProfile server to check if logged user is allowed to use this adapter method or not by checking this on server level." .....

MF can be integrated directly to LDAP through liberty to perform the user authentication and access control so have you considered that ? Any limitation there to implement your use case ?

Comment: Yes I considered that, but this require additional development. I had hoped it will work out of the box.